# the last battle that counts

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "the last thing that counts" in the following passage? It is from the book “Persian Gulf Command” by Ashley Jackson, p. 346.

> It was a question of robbing Peter to pay Paul – but Paul kept coming back for more. Given this situation, Kennedy understood that patience was a virtue, and that not losing in the most strategically important regions was the key to ultimate victory. Though the idea might have brought colour to the cheeks of the notoriously impatient prime minister, the secret was to ‘hold our own and gradually harbour our resources which were slowly growing’. ‘It is unfortunate,’ Kennedy continued, ‘that so much time is
> required for the development of the full power of the British Empire and of America. But this has to be accepted. And we must find consolation in the fact that **it is the last battle that counts**.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your research. For example, [count](https://www.lexico.com/definition/count) sense 3.1 seems to fit.

Comment: It means while the British were often losing ground and strategically ceding territory, it was the final confrontation that would ultimately lead to the end  of German occupation.The same thing happened in Libya and then Egypt in 1942 (Battle of El Alamein) , and Vietnam in 1968 (Tet offensive) and again later in 1973

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It is the last battle that counts" in this context of war means that although all the battles that precede that last one might be important, losing them or losing some of them is far from being as bad as losing the last one, this being so because when you have lost the last battle you have lost the war, whereas when you have won that last battle, no matter what losses you suffered before that, you have won the war.

Comment: Shame that the OP did not read the text: "Not losing in the most strategically important regions was the key to *ultimate victory*."